# DDMS perspective not showing to save the Heap dump

Tags: android, ddms, eclipse-memory-analyzer

Can anybody tell me how to save the Heap dump file through DDMS perspective.
While clicking on "Dump HPROF file" Button it is not showing any dialog to save the file.
I want to use this Hprof file in Memory Analyser tool. Please let me know ASAP

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this same problem the solution is to go to: 
Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS 
and change the field 'HPROF Action' to 'Save to Disk'.